# Binding const references to const values only

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, reference, constants

I am working on a code that finds pairs (using a specific condition) among the elements of a collection. I don't really want to duplicate the elements of the collection, so I figured I would use pointer pairs. This however is unsafe if the values in the original collection can change.

In my code I would like to use a const reference that only binds to truly constant values (because I don't want to let the users to abuse the pairs). This approach however:

```
using PairCollectionType =
    std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<Cluster>, std::shared_ptr<Cluster>>>;

PairCollectionType getClusterPairCollection(
    const std::vector<Cluster> const& clusterCollection)
{
    // ...
}
```

-> results an error of "duplicate 'const'". I know that this is possible with pointers:

```
const ptr_type* const ptrThatBindsOnlyToConsts;
```

Is this somehow possible with references too?

Comment: A reference is `const` by default. Once you "reference" it to something, it's done, it will always reference the same object. If you write `ref = new_object;`, the reference is not changing, it just assigns to the referenced object with `new_object`.

Comment: You have 2 `const` to the left of the `&` in `const std::vector<Cluster> const& clusterCollection`.  You are only allowed one.

Comment: `ptrThatBindsOnlyToConsts` can point to non-const objects. E.g. `int x = 5; const int *const y = &x;`. The second `const` means that it cannot be set to point to something else, other than what it is initialized to point to.

Comment: It might help people to understand what problem you are trying to solve, if you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which compiles, but you would prefer it gave a compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about your rationale for needing to do this. But you can give a compilation error if the caller passes a non-const argument, by adding overloads to catch those cases:

```
void func(U const &)
{
    // the real code
}

void func(U &) = delete;
void func(U&&) = delete;

int main()
{
    U u;
    U const cu {};

    func(cu);    // OK
    func(u);     // error
    func(U{});   // error
}
```